# dynamically add contols in ruby on rails form using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to add controls dynamically using javascript add button. 
It is working fine with simple strings in javascript as follows:

```
 var input="";
 input2 = "<select name='parameterUniversity["+ updated_row_num +"]' id='ddl_university'>";
 for(i=0;i<10<i++)
    input += "<option  value='"+i+"'>" + i + "</option>";
 input+="</select>";
```

but when i try to use

```
 var input="";
 input = "<select name='parameterUniversity["+ updated_row_num +"]' id='ddl_university'>";
 <% @Universites.each_with_index do |u| %>
    input += "<option text='" +<%= u.University %>+ "' value='" + <%= u.id %> + "'>" + <%= u.University %> + "</option>";
 <% end %>  
 input+="</select>";
```

it submits the page when i click on Add button, please let me know what i have done wrong. it should work as we are replacing simple string with this server type string.

**Edit**
Error in console is

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

i am unable to locate this error

Regards.

Comment: change the input type from submit to button and click the add button and observe the JavaScript error in console and post the error too.

Comment: is there any error marked in your script-let?

Comment: Some tips that probably doesn't fix your main issue but you should also fix. You should use `@Universites.each do |u|`, also the first letter on a variable as capital is wrong, it should be `@universites` and lastly the plural for university is universities.

Comment: Thanks @NishadNichoos problem was with concatenation and trailing white spaces. i actually took gap of 2-3 months from RoR and this was the result. Thanks again guys :)